# Coded UI Testing Mouse.StartDragging works once and then stops working

Tags: drag-and-drop, coded-ui-tests

I have a Coded UI Test which I have Moved to UIMap.cs (so that I can edit the  code) and my code is ...

```
    public void Drag_Item(Point from, Point to)
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfPane uIItemPane = this.UIOMyWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIItemTabList.UIControlTabPage.UIControlText.UIItemPane;
        #endregion

        Mouse.StartDragging(uIItemPane, from);
        Mouse.StopDragging(uIItemPane, to);
    }
```

I call this method in my test ...

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Drag_3_Items()
    {
        Positions positions = new Positions();
        Point start = positions.adaptorsAlert;
        this.UIMap.Drag_Item(start, positions.pos1);
        this.UIMap.Drag_Item(start, positions.pos2);
        this.UIMap.Drag_Item(start, positions.pos3);
        this.UIMap.Close_AdaptorsWindowOnDesignGrid();
    }
```

My problem is that the first call to Drag_Item works but the second call and third call do not. After the first drag has worked, the cursor goes back to my window icon which is correct then it waits indefinitely. If I wiggle the mouse it suddenly works. I obviously won't be there to wiggle the mouse when my tests are running on their own so how do I fix this? I have tried many things including adding various Thread.Sleep lines, Mouse.Hover and Mouse.Move. Nothing except physically moving my mouse with my hand works though. Other people have posted the same question in various forums with no good answers.

For info my Positions class is ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyCodedUITesting
{
//[Serializable]
public class Positions
{
    public Point pos1 = new Point(40, -500);
    public Point Pos1
    {
        get { return pos1 ; }
        set { this.pos1  = value; }
    }

    public Point pos2 = new Point(440, -500);
    public Point Pos2
    {
        get { return pos2 ; }
        set { this.pos2  = value; }
    }

    public Point pos3 = new Point(840, -500);
    public Point Pos3
    {
        get { return pos3 ; }
        set { this.pos3  = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is that you're re instantiating uIItemPane every time you call the method. You may want to instantiate it inside your test method and then pass it to Drag_Item.

Comment: Sorry Ryanman, that didn't make any difference. It still works on the first attempt but fails on subsequent attempts to drag and drop.

Comment: Two more suggestions - try calling Mouse.Move(uIItemPane,from); before your start dragging.


Second suggestion is that the item pane you're relying on may be incorrect. Looking at the control hierarchy, it looks like you're looking inside a pane which is inside a text box. I of course don't know your scenario but my gut says that your parent control should be something different.

Comment: Thanks Ryanman, I have tried Mouse.Move but it doesn't work either I'm afraid. I have tried Mouse.Hover as well. On the second suggestion, yes it is a pane inside a text box but that's what the dev team have created so I can't change it. It does work the first time so it must be correct at some point. Interestingly I have noticed that it sometimes stops working first time and then starts working on the first attempt again later. It's as if there's something fishy happening with the state of the mouse.